Could it be illegal to register ones child at state school when one has no intention of sending them?
It is in the news that a "parent action group" on Facebook is encouraging members to register at state schools even if they don't want to take up a place.  This is a protest against Labour plans to end private schools charitable status and make them liable for VAT.
On the assumption that to register at state school requires filling in a form that says one intends to send ones child there, and one did that while posting online that one was just doing it as a protest and had no intention of sending their child to that school, could one face any criminal or other charges?
The story focuses on Edinburgh in Scotland, one can imagine similar protests south of the border so answers for either jurisdiction would be relevant.
